Why is my machine not using swap memory?
I have a Rocky Linux installation with ~80 GB RAM, I configured it to use 75 GB swap
However, when I look at the results of "bashtop", I get the following result

Any indications as to why my instance is going all in on memory in stead of swap?
Kind regards

Why wouldn’t it go all in on RAM? Swap is “bad”, so you wouldn’t use unless you have to. // What’s your swapiness value? Also, what’s the current frontswap size?

I have multiple .net API backends running in systemd services, when a service is started, will it always use RAM or will it use SWAP in case it needs to do some calculations or access the database? swapiness value is 30, frontswap size: Size: 78643196  &  Used: 61184

Again: Why would it use swap when RAM is available? Please explain in your question the reasoning why you think it should be using swap. (And while you’re at it, also add the information from your comment to the question.)
